# What is simpliest way to set current local time on <input type="datetime-local">

Tags: javascript, html, datetime, input

What would be the simpliest way to set current local time on input of 'datetime-local' type?
I know that this is really simple:

```
new Date().toISOString().substr(0, 19)
```

but it doesn't consider the time zone.

So far the simplest solution which considers the localtime, that I have found:

```
var currentDate = new Date()
currentDate(currentDate().getTime() - currentDate().getTimezoneOffset() * 60000).toISOString().substring(0, 19)
console.log(currentDate)
```

Aren't there any simpler solutions to set default current local time?

Comment: Note that Firefox, IE, and Opera do not support `datetime-local`.

Comment: If you want the user's local timezone, why are you converting the date into the UTC-based `toISOString`?   `new Date()` is already in the user's local zone.

Comment: Daniel Beck, but you can't assign new Date() to input of datatime-local, it won't show anything, since the format must be ex. "2018-10-19T00:00:00"